# Approach to running long tasks on django to produce a dashboard

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a django site, I currently use it as a frontend to kick backend tasks (using celery). The tasks usually take about 5 minutes and produce a .txt file.

I want to run the same analysis but instead of spitting a .txt file I want to display data on a dashboard.

I'm concerned about time-out issues as processing takes about 5min. 
Alternatively, could I set up a 'loading' message to prevent timeout issues?

Best practices, ideas or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: have you considered using sockets?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/   I have never heard about sockets